VS Code Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation text on its own new line
I can't seem to get wrapped text on its own line using Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation.
This works for regular Emmet abbreviations but not "Wrap with Abbreviation"
"emmet.preferences": {
    "output.inlineBreak": 1,
    "format.forceIndentationForTags": [
        "div",
        "p"
    ]
},

I have also tried.
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
  "html": {
     "tag_nl": true
  }
}

But nothing seems to work.
Any help would be appreciated.
<p>
    This is what is expected
</p>

<p>This is what I get</p>


https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/237053

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20state%3Aclosed%20label%3Aemmet%20wrap%20indent I suggest you raise a bug ticket. if you do, please add a link here to your ticket.
